# how to transfer files from galaxy nexus running ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have installed ubuntu touch in my galaxy nexus. But now I want to  transfer some files from computer to it. When I connect to windows pc, errors in MTP, and when connect to linux minty, not detecting at all. Now i have no way to transfer files. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Touch does not support mtp file transfer yet. The best way to transfer files is via sftp. Here is how to enable and use sftp:

(Before starting make sure your nexus is connected to the same LAN as your desktop)

### 1 - Install OpenSSH

Open terminal on ubuntu desktop with your nexus devices connected via usb and run these commands in this order:

**1st:** `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb`

**2nd:** `sudo adb root`

**3rd:** `adb shell`

**3.5th..** If you are using the developer preview `ubuntu_chroot` (If you don't know, it can't hurt to try this step.)

**4th**: `apt-get install openssh-server`

### 2 - Connect to nexus via sftp

**1st:** Open nautilus (the file manager) in ubuntu desktop and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to open the address bar

**2nd:** Enter `sftp://phablet@YOURNEXUSIP` into the address bar.
(obviously replace *YOURNEXUSIP* with the ip address of your nexus which you can find by logining into the adb shell and running `ifconfig`

**3rd:** When prompted for a password enter `phablet`

**4th:** If you did everything correctly you should now have access to the root file system as the user "phablet"

Comment: To install SSH (on Ubuntu Touch), try (**Step 4.**) **`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`**. Its not **openssh** (client) you need, that is already present. *I use SSH and SFTP all the time, for Touch 13.10 beta (on Nexus 7).*

Comment: I believe openssh will install both openssh-client and openssh-server packages but i'll change the instructions just to be sure.